# Kafka with Java: how to re-read data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, commit, kafka-consumer-api

I have the following problem with the kafka API. I set up my consumer with:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, configuration.batchSize);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

Then

```
while(true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(200));
    try {
         //do some update in DB in a transaction
         consumer.commitSync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I want to read data from Kafka, update a database from this data. But if the update fails, I want to retry until it works. So I'd like to apply the DB transaction to kafka, i.a. if my DB transaction is OK then move the kafka pointer, but if it failes then retry from the same position.

In my code,

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(
```

is not working as expected, it means "if kafka crashes, then restart from the commited position". But when my DB transaction fails, even if I don't commitAsync() the pointer is gone forward.

My question is: is there a simple way to reverse the kafka pointer position, to the position of the last poll.

I already noticed there is, in the API

```
public void seek(TopicPartition partition,
             long offset);
```

but this requires to maintain manually a list of partitions with their offset, I guess there is something simplier and more elegant?

Comment: In the past i have used a dead letter queue to address this issue
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue
https://eng.uber.com/reliable-reprocessing/

Comment: `if kafka crashes, then restart from the commited position. But when my DB transaction fails, even if I don't commitAsync() the pointer is gone forward.`

 can we discuss about this more? what exactly happening ?

Comment: *update a database from this data* -- I would strongly recommend Kafka Connect rather than write a plain consumer, which handles offsets for you internally and will not move them if the database transaction fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since the consumer.poll is inside a loop, you will keep moving forward with the offsets irrespective of whether you commit the offsets or not. Commit comes in handy only when you restart the component. Ie to know the position from where the consumer should start consuming from.

2) In case you need to move to the previously committed offset when the DB transaction fails, then use the seek method in Kafka Consumer. 
    public void seek(TopicPartition partition,long offset)

3) For committing the offsets for the individual partitions, you will need to maintain the offset per partition as what you had mentioned. I dont think there is any other way.

You may not need to seek to the previously committed offset every time the DB Transaction fails. You might want to pause your consumer and retry few times increasing the wait time exponentially.

But to answer your question as to how to move to the previous offset with every poll, have a track of the offset of the first message in every partition and in case of failure, at the end of the loop, seek to the offset that you have a track of.

Comment: 'You may not need to seek to the previously committed offset every time the DB Transaction fails. You might want to pause your consumer and retry few times increasing the wait time exponentially.' is what I did: if the DB update fails, I retry the update until it's OK, then I commit the kafka position. This ensures that all the messages in kafka are processed into the DB. Thanks.